# Pytest not running conftest.py at all

Tags: pytest

I'm running pytest version 6.0.1

In the root of my project I have tests/x dirs

```
% ls tests/x
__init__.py     __pycache__     conftest.py     test_x.py
```

conftest.py contains:

```
print('IN CONFTEST')


def pytest_sessionstart(session):
    print('SESSIONSTART')
```

test_x.py contains:

```
def test_x():
    print("X")
```

It appears nothing in conftest.py runs when I run pytest:

```
% pytest tests/x -s
=================================================================================================== test session starts ===================================================================================================
platform darwin -- Python 3.8.5, pytest-6.0.1, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: OMITTED (It's the parent of "tests")
collected 1 item                                                                                                                                                                                                          

tests/x/test_x.py X
.

==================================================================================================== 1 passed in 0.01s ====================================================================================================
```

I'm completely stumped. I haven't found anything about anyone with an issue like this. Help!

Comment: Have you tried to use `python -m pytest ...` instead to ensure that the root path is included in the Python path?

Comment: Yes, same result with "python -m pytest tests/x -s"

Comment: That is indeed very strange. Could it be a permission issue? What is the output of something like `ls -ls tests/x`? Unlikely, but just in case...

Comment: It can access the test files just fine, so I doubt it. `% ls -l tests/x  
total 16  
-rw-r--r--  1 jason.brooks  staff    0 Sep 10 10:12 __init__.py  
drwxr-xr-x  4 jason.brooks  staff  128 Sep 10 10:12 __pycache__  
-rw-r--r--  1 jason.brooks  staff   85 Sep 10 10:09 conftest.py  
-rw-r--r--  1 jason.brooks  staff   29 Sep 10 10:12 test_x.py`

Comment: Yeah, didn't really expect it... Does it behave the same way if you move the `conftest.py` one level up?

Comment: Yep, same exact thing happens if I move it to tests/conftest.py

Comment: So pytest doesn't load `conftest.py` at all, it seems... Do you have any pytest plug-ins installed? I didn't see any in your output, but maybe you have omitted that...

Comment: Nope! Not that I know of at least. I didn't omit anything but rootdir in the output.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped, too. Next thing I would probably do is reinstall pytest, or try a 5.x version. And if that doesn't help, try to debug pytest...

Answer (score 0):

Update: Reinstalling pytest seems to have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since I kept stumbling here, I will leave what I found and what might be your issue too:

For me, it was a basic mistake. Reading pytest doc made it clear.

I was writing my test like this:

```
class Test2(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_new_valid_event(self, hello):
        print(hello)
```

This did not work as 'hello', my fixture was not found.
Removing the unittest.TestCase fixed it.

```
class Test2:
    def test_new_valid_event(self, hello):
        print(hello)
```

Pytest does not support manual loaded fixtures. Only auto ones. So please check if this is the reason for your issue.

My setup:

- conftest.py in same folder as in the test file.
- I run the test with `python -m pytest test_file.py`
- I also have a dunder 'init.py' file in the tests folder